# CodeIgniter - get error messages

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I created my own custom error page by changing the line in config.php

```
$route['404_override'] = 'main/_404';
```

So now it loads the correct page, by loading the _404 function in my controller

The issue is, I still want to be able to get a hold of the $heading & $message error variables displayed in the default page, which show up as:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1><?php echo $heading; ?></h1>
    <?php echo $message; ?>
</div>
```

Here's my _404 function if anyone can give me some advice how to add those variables I would greatly appreciate it

```
public function _404() {
        $data['query'] = array('title' => 'Page not found.', 'keywords' => '', 'description' => 'Page not found', 'page' => 'error');


        $this->load->view('parts/head',$data);
        $this->load->view('parts/_404');// <- would go here
        $this->load->view('parts/footer');
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, actually, two things:

1) In your re-routed 404 page, you should be able to pass regularly any variable you want, so you can simply  `$this->load->view('parts/_404',$data);` and have there available your variables.

2) if you're talking about the default 404 page, keep in mind that it can't be overridden under certain circustamces, that is when the `show_404()` core function is called:

> It won't affect to the show_404() function, which will continue
>   loading the default error_404.php file at
>   application/errors/error_404.php.

This function belongs to the Exception handler class. There, in fact, at line 90 you have

```
function show_404($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)
    {
        $heading = "404 Page Not Found";
        $message = "The page you requested was not found.";

        // By default we log this, but allow a dev to skip it
        if ($log_error)
        {
            log_message('error', '404 Page Not Found --> '.$page);
        }

        echo $this->show_error($heading, $message, 'error_404', 404);
        exit;
    }
```

which in turn calls the `show_error()` method wich sets the **header error code** (4th argument) and **adds** the specified **view** (3rd argument) to the view buffer.

As you can see messages are here hardcoded inside the method. If you want a total customization you can either override *this* method (make it, for example, call another function within the same class) or simply hardcode other message there instead.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't realize they were static variables